# Docker start fails with "listen tcp 172.18.0.1:9323: bind: cannot assign requested address"

Tags: docker

My docker demon has fail. And stack in failed state

```
:~$ sudo systemctl start docker.service
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

in logs i have next errors

```
sudo journalctl -f -u docker
-- Logs begin at Thu 2019-12-05 10:38:54 MSK. --
Dec 24 23:45:16 dockerd[11268]: listen tcp 172.18.0.1:9323: bind: cannot assign requested address
Dec 24 23:45:16 systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 24 23:45:16 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 24 23:45:16 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 24 23:45:18 systemd[1]: docker.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Dec 24 23:45:18 systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Dec 24 23:45:18 systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Dec 24 23:45:18 systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 24 23:45:18 systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 24 23:45:18 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

no process run locally on the port

```
:~$ lsof -i tcp:9323
:~$ fuser -n tcp -k 9323
:~$
```

uninstall and then install docker didn't help, still same problem

```
:~$ sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
containerd.io is already the newest version (1.2.10-3).
docker-ce-cli is already the newest version (5:19.03.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic).
docker-ce is already the newest version (5:19.03.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 212 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up docker-ce (5:19.03.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) ...
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d
           └─override.conf
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-12-25 00:09:41 MSK; 12ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 3577 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --experimental=true --metrics-addr 172.18.0.1:9323 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3577 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
```

Comment: Did you check if the port 9323 is already assigned to other process ?

Comment: yes, it is free according to lsof/fuser

Answer (score 0):

One of previous admins have create `override.conf`

```
:~$ cat /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/override.conf
[Service]
LimitMEMLOCK=infinity
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock --experimental=true --metrics-addr 172.18.0.1:9323
```

Seems that there should be some servis at `172.18.0.1:9323` that have fail